# Get a subset of items using .WHERE and then REMOVEALL by condition using Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I have a list of items, these items have a property called vog_code, it is an int, this list have a variety of items with 4 different types of vog_code, 1,10,14,16.

Now, I want to remove the items on that list that doesnt abide to a certain date, but for items with vog_codes equals 14 and 16 the condition will be different.

This is the expression I have now:

```
transaccionSinAgruparResp.ListaDeTransacciones.RemoveAll(x => x.vog_code == 14 || x.vog_code == 16 && x.fecha_recepcion >= fechaOriginal);
```

Which is incorrect since it will eliminate all the items with vog_code 14 and 16 and doesnt abide the `AND` operator.

Is there any way to ask "for these elements that are vog_code 14 and 16 I then, will check if the dates are greater or equal".

I tried with a `.Where` and then `.RemoveAll` but that is not possible.

I dont want to use more an auxiliary list unless it is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If I correctly understand your goal, this should be what you need.

The key difference is the use of `()` to group the 2 `vog_code` conditions.

This will remove all items where BOTH of the following are true

- `vog_code` is either 14 or 16
- `fecha_recepcion >= fechaOriginal`

```cs
transaccionSinAgruparResp.ListaDeTransacciones.RemoveAll(x => (x.vog_code == 14 || x.vog_code == 16) && x.fecha_recepcion >= fechaOriginal);
```

#### Another way

Another approach to this is to switch your conditions around a bit like this:

```cs
transaccionSinAgruparResp.ListaDeTransacciones.RemoveAll(x => x.fecha_recepcion >= fechaOriginal && x.vog_code == 14 || x.vog_code == 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is a higher precedence than the || operator. If you want || to be executed before &&, then you need to wrap it in ().